# A gap between header and navigation bar

Tags: html, css

i just started learning html and css and tried to do a basic website. But there is a gap between my header picture and my navigation bar and i can't seem to find the problem.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<img src="images/banner.gif">
</div>
<div class=navigationbar margin="auto">
<ul>
<div class="color_change">
<li><a href='change_color.php?w=1'><img src='images/black.png'></a></li>
<li><a href='change_color.php?w=2'><img src='images/blanched_almond.png'></a></li>
<li><a href='change_color.php?w=3'><img src='images/orange.png'></a></li>
<li><a href='change_color.php?w=4'><img src='images/dark_red.png'></a></li></div>
<div class=masa>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
 margin: 0%;
 padding: 0%;
 text-decoration: none;
}

body{
background-image: url(../images/backgroundimage.gif);
}

.navigationbar {
background-color: #101010;
width: 100%;
margin: 0%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: fyi: `<div>` is now allowd inside `<ul>`, only `<li>`, `<script>` or `<template>`. `margin="auto"` sound like it should be `style="margin:auto"`. Add a class to the `<div>` surrounding your banner and set its margin and padding to 0.

Comment: Please only add relevant tags. This issue doesn't seem to be related to PHP at all.

Comment: @brombeer Thanks for telling me. I've tried what you told but nothing changed.

Comment: Might be the image then. Does it happen in all browsers or just a specific one?

Comment: @brombeer ahhh that seems to be the case. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to close ul tag and maybe remove the masa class if it's not used.

Comment: I've added </ul> before the </div> and removed the masa class but still nothing changed.

Comment: try to remove the background-color of .navigationbar